# Are there softboxes that will work both with portable speedlights and and with studio flashes (Bowens Gemini 400RX)?

Tags: flash, hotshoe-flash, studio, softbox, portable

I'm very interested in acquiring a softbox with a honeycomb grid of about 150cm. Here is one of those: [http://www.amazon.com/Lightstand-Octagonal-Honeycomb-Internal-Visico/dp/B00NRZE5MY/ref=sr_1_5?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1422065047&sr=1-5&keywords=octabox+honeycomb](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NRZE5MY)

It'd fit to my Bowens studio flashes, and that's good, but will I be able to use it with portable speedlights? What else would I need to buy in order to do that? Or are there models designed to be used with both kind of lights? Can you point me to them?

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get a speedlight to Bowens S mount adapter made by the manufacture of light modifier. Adorama's Glow line offers this option.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like [this adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JAAXH1A), which will accept a Bowen's S type modifier mount and hold pretty much any speedlight.  The mount in the octobox you linked to is the right type.